# KVM, qemu, libvirt no internet connection (or dhcp) on NAT

Tags: networking, kvm, qemu, nat, libvirt

I have configured (using virt-manager) a NAT network with dhcp as follows:

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>dbbdc0dd-20d8-41df-aadb-d8a106170c2b</uuid>
  <forward dev="enp0s31f6" mode="nat">
    <nat>
      <port start="1024" end="65535"/>
    </nat>
  <interface dev="enp0s31f6"/>
  </forward>
  <bridge name="virbr1" stp="on" delay="0"/>
  <mac address="52:54:00:82:1d:b8"/>
  <domain name="default"/>
  <ip address="192.168.104.1" netmask="255.255.255.0">
    <dhcp>
      <range start="192.168.104.128" end="192.168.104.254"/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

Iptables rules are: https://pastebin.com/SRW9mgkP
I have tried:

1. disabling firewalld, iptables and docker
2. changing firewalld backend to iptables
3. mix and match of commands for iptables
4. macvtap does work but only if there is just one network interface in the VM. When I had a second nic with an isolated network it stops working.

I have used tcpdump on the interface and I can see that the VM is trying to do some dhcp requests but there are no replies. I also have no internet even if I manually set the IP. Maybe it is a newbie problem but how can I make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try install "ebtables, dnsmasq" and see if that will work and restart libvirtd service.

Comment: They were already installed on my system.

Comment: UPDATE: I can ping host and guest in both ways but that is it.

Comment: UPDATE UPDATE: I have been at this for countless hours. At the end, after every solution, I just came up with the idea of disabling nftables.service in systemd just in case it was interfering and IT WORKED.